# Print the value of specific key from Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key-value

I have `Input.txt` and the contents of this file are:

```
Name1=Value1
Name2=Value2
Name3=Value3
```

Desired output: get the value of `key==Name1`.

Condition: This needs to be implemented by Dictionary in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as param_file:
    text = param_file.readlines()
    d = dict(x.strip().split("=") for x in text)
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == "Name1":
            print(f"{d[k]}")
```

Comment: I see you've answered your own question. You are finding the key, value of the dictionary in the worst way possible though...

Comment: Easier way is more appreciated. You can post your answer. @tomjn

Comment: Just `print(d["Name1"])` if you know the key, no need to iterate over the entire dictionary

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Also is there any way I can apply function similar to ```strip``` to integer values? I have a IP and wants the output of only after third ```.```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as param_file:
    text = param_file.readlines()
    dc = {y.split("=")[0]:y.split("=")[1] for y in text}
    print(dc["Name1"]) if "Name1" in dc else None
```

That will output

```
Value1
```